# Uploading multiple files with curl results in empty IFormFile list

Tags: c#, curl, file-upload, asp.net-core

I have an ASP Net Core controller which I want to use to upload several files. I've followed the instructions in [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-2.1). My controller declaration looks like this:

```
[HttpPost("/api/v1.0/assets/{id}")]
public async Task<ApiResponse<Exception>> Post(string id, List<IFormFile> files)
```

To test if the controller works I called it using curl, like this:

```
curl -v -X POST -F "files[]=@thing.json" -F "files[]=@thing.zip" -H 'X-Custom-header1:abc1234' -H 'X-Custom-Header2:abc1234' http://localhost:57535/api/v1.0/assets/asset00134
```

but I get an empty `files` list. However, If I inspect the value of `HttpContext.Request` I find `HttpContext.Request.Form.Files.Count=2` and all the information about my files (name, length, etc.) is there and is correct.

Why is it not being mapped to my `List<IFormFile>` parameter?

I've done a search through the internet but in all examples I've been able to find the code is the same, like mine, so I do not understand where is the difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved. It was a silly mistake on my side. If you set the name of you `List<IFormFile>` instance to `files` then in the curl command you have to name it `files`, and not `files[]` as I did. It worked like a charm after fixing that.